# How does a CCD able to differentiate between different colors?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device#Color_cameras),

> Digital color cameras generally use a Bayer mask over the CCD. Each
>   square of four pixels has one filtered red, one blue, and two green [...].
>   The result of this is that luminance information is collected at every
>   pixel, but the color resolution is lower than the luminance
>   resolution.

So unlike in [3CCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-CCD_camera), where light is split into 3 different chips, in a regular CCD the same chip (same semiconductor) is used to capture different colors (after the light passes through the Bayer mask). But if it's the same semiconductor (same bandgap), how can it be sensitive to red, green and blue and the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silicon is sensitive to a range of wavelenghts from UV to near IR.

[image]

Range of Kodak CCD's quantum efficiency - the proportion of photons that are detected - at each wavelength

The same thing applies to 3-CCD cameras, the 3 color CCDs are identical, it is only the color splitting prism that decides which detects what color